# How to make TrackPoint and TouchPad work together 18.04

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptic, trackpoint, libinput

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 I discovered quite different trackpoint (stick) and touchpad behaviour, specifically, the trackpoint and touchpad would not work together (however the trackpoint and a mouse would work together).

Dell Precision 7510, upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

Comment: Lenovo Thinkpad p71 20HKCTO1WW touchpad tap function does not work on Ubuntustudio 18.4. Any workaround? What am I doing wrong? TY

Answer (score 1):

After much fussing about attempting to configure `libinput` drivers, the desired behaviour returned by installing the older `synaptic` driver (Ubuntu 18.04 appears to ship with the new `libinput` drivers) and rebooting the machine.

libinput drivers:
`xserver-xorg-input-libinput`

synaptics (deprecated?):
`xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`